# Is there a function in JavaFX that allows you to click a hyperlink and have it open in a Browser such as Chrome or Firefox?

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

This is what I have so far, but I am struggling with the handle.

```
    @FXML
    public void link() {
        hypTerms.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent e) {
                ;
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work :

```
Hyperlink link = new Hyperlink("Click me");
String url = "https://www.google.com/";
link.setOnAction(a->getHostServices().showDocument(url));
```

It will automatically open the page in your default browser.

Comment: You're a wizard! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this with all exception handled.

```
                    String link = "https://google.com"

                    try {
                            Desktop.getDesktop().browse(new URL(link).toURI())
                        }
                        catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        catch (URISyntaxException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
```